# Using vstest.console.exe TestCategory with equals and not equals

Tags: unit-testing, specflow, vstest

I am using SpecFlow to write Gherkin for automated UI tests.  We have multiple tags (@smoke, @on, @off, etc.).

Test A has tags @smoke
Test B has tags @smoke @off

These are translated to vstest test categories and do not include the @ symbol.

I want to run test A but not test B.

This is what is not working.  It runs all @smoke tests.

Vstest.console.exe mytest.dll /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=smoke&TestCategory!=off"

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Test Runner are you using? NUnit, MSTest, XUnit, SpecFlow+Runner?

Comment: specflow.mstest.  I'm actually executing vstest.console.exe as I'm using visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 17):

I had two issues.

1. I was executing the test with Thoughtworks Go which did weird things with the quotes before executing the command
2. I needed to surround the entire condition with parenthesis as such: `Vstest.console.exe mytest.dll /TestCaseFilter:"(TestCategory=smoke&TestCategory!=off)"`

Comment: Parenthesis was it!  Here's what I had to put in the TFS Test Filter criteria:  `(TestCategory!=Nightly&TestCategory!=Ignore)`.  My goal was to run all unit tests except those in the above categories.  Basically I wanted to run all tests that I didn't assign a category.

Comment: I could not execute with the category but without category it works fine. The issue it says is the file not found